# Is there a way to specify library types and versions on GitHub other than using requirement.txt?

Tags: python, django, github

I've been exploring different approaches to specify library types and versions on GitHub for my solo project using Django and React. In my research, I've predominantly come across the use of requirement.txt files for managing project libraries.

I've tried reviewing documentation and online discussions, but I'm curious to hear from the community about their experiences. Specifically, I'm interested in knowing if using requirement.txt is a widely adopted practice in the industry for managing project dependencies. Additionally, I'm open to learning about alternative methods that developers might find effective.

What approaches have you tried for specifying library types and versions in your GitHub projects, and what were your expectations regarding the ease of maintenance and collaboration?

Thank you for sharing your insights!